Is this epsilon-delta proof for a complex limit correct?
I want to prove that:
$$\lim_{z\to0}\sqrt z = 0$$
Where $\sqrt{re^{i\varphi}} := \sqrt re^{i\varphi/2}$ is the principal complex square root. Using the following definition:
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=\ell\in\mathbb C\iff\forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0:0<|z-z_0|<\delta\implies|f(z)-\ell|<\varepsilon$$
I have to find $\delta(\varepsilon)$ such that:
$$0<|z|<\delta(\varepsilon)\implies|\sqrt z|<\varepsilon$$
Since $|\sqrt z|=\sqrt{|z|}$, writing $z$ as $a+ib$, the condition becomes:
$$0<\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}<\delta\implies\sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}<\varepsilon$$
So it's sufficient to choose $\delta=\varepsilon^2$.
Is this correct? Also, I kind of "made up" the definition of complex limit, since I couldn't find anything on the internet from a reliable source. Could you link something to read about the topic?
Thanks in advance.

Well done for generalising the notion of a limit in $\mathbb{R}$ to one in $\mathbb{C}$, but do note that you have not invented something new, and that limits are defined for arbitrary metric spaces, which the complex numbers are a particular example of

Expanding on @Carlyle's comment: as long as we have some "distance functions" with appropriate properties on the function's domain and codomain, we replace $|a-b|$ with $d(a,b)$ to get the general definition of limit. And yes, nicely reasoned.

@Carlyle thanks, so is the proof correct?

@aschepler thanks. Is the proof correct anyway?

@Elvis it is correct in the sense that you found a suitable $\delta(\varepsilon)$. It is lacking a bit in detail, but presumably you know how to expand on that if necessary
